Joining long stair treads
I'm finishing a 3-seasons room and need to make a set of stairs to go from my house to my room.  I have double French doors and the width is a little under 6 feet.  The longest stair tread I've found is 4 feet.  So, it looks like I'll have to join the edges to make the stair tread.
It's only 2 steps, so I'm not going to make stringers.  I'm just going to make 2 framed "boxes" under the steps, so the treads will be continuously bearing on a 2x4.
My plan of attack was to just cut 2 equally sized pieces and join these end to end with some dowels.  Just wondering if anyone else has ever done this or if there is a better way.

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. It's one query per Question here on SE, so I've edited out the second query. That's not a good fit for the SE model anyway as it's subjective what you can/should do here. There's no reason your plan of attack wouldn't work – given recent insights into end grain butt joints a plain butt might even be enough – but dowels would be my personal choice here too.

This would also be a much better fit at [diy.se] than at [woodworking.se]. Maybe a mod will migrate it.

While your idea will work fine, I’m surprised that you can’t find 6’ long pieces of wood.

There's nothing that says you must use a pre-fab "stair tread" for stair treads. You can use any piece of wood you'd like. You might need to do a little milling on it (maybe use a router and a round over bit to make the nose of the thread look nicer), but then you can do exactly what you need/want without having to be beholden to what someone else thinks a stair tread should be.

@FreeMan, I figured this would be a better place for the question since it deals with joinery and finishing wood planks and you all would have more expertise in that area vs the generic home improvement section.  Hard to find around here 1" thick x 12 inches wide pieces of wood in order to mill them down, so joining prefab treads is kind of my only option.

No local lumber yards? No, not big box stores selling construction lumber and a couple of bd/ft of hardwood, an actual, real-live lumber yard? No small business guys with a portable band-saw mill going around looking for downed trees?

2-6” wide boards? Order online?  You could do 3/4 stock and then glue/ profile a thicker nosing.

@FreeMan, what type of wood would you use to make the treads?  Will probably stain them.
